# Keyframes don't show unless 'show only selected' isn't checked

Tags: keyframes

I'm having problems getting keyframes to show without showing all, which is a mess to wade through. Any pointers?

The attached file (if I can figure out how to use Blender-exchange) contains a simple plane with a material with a mix transparency. It mixes with a transparent shader, to give a disappearing effect to the plane.

In the animation window, selecting the plane doesn't show the keyframes that exist unless I show all. In a big project, this is a chore. What am I missing?

Thanks!

(2.93.5)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the keyframes for the *Mix Shader* you need to enable the *Only Show Selected* option, then open the *Shader Editor* and select the *Mix Shader* node.

Comment: Thank you! I had another project that I was showing the keyframes for, and didn't realize that was why!